# Use Case Diagram for Stack Overflow

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case, use-case-diagram, requirements-management

I am trying to design a `Use Case Diagram` for an app like `Stack Overflow`. I have tried to add some basic functionalities in this diagram.

[image: UML Diagram]

I want to improve this diagram to include an exhaustive list of all the features of Stack Overflow, but have no idea of how to do so. Also, should there be another actor for `Admin` who manages user accounts, or not? And if we are asked for `Use Cases`, should we describe the inner functionalities, preconditions and postconditions of each use case separately?

What if other than these two actors, I decide to add a `Mediator` actor too, who forwards the problems to the mentor, and when a mentor solves it, it is the responsibility of mediator to mark it solved?

Comment: Not going to make an answer again, but `Login` is no use case. It is a simple constraint. Btw.: your actors look very male... could someone get upset about it?

Comment: @ThomasKilian ^^ they seem are also very intelligent, look at the size of their head

Comment: @ThomasKilian I really did not intend to make them look male. (Well I am a proud female ;) ), somehow they really do look male .

Comment: @bruno Intelligent humans (both genders) ;)

Comment: @ThomasKilian Login doesn't really solve a user problem. But it is an important part of any app. Should I move it into preconditions then?

Comment: @Nisha to avoid that again use an UML modeler, some are free ;-)

Comment: @Nisha yes the best place for _login_ is in pre condition

Comment: Yes. A precondition is a good place. Alternatively you can attach the constraint to the actors (e.g. `{ must be logged in for all UCs }` or for and admin `{ no login required}`).

Comment: @bruno I will surely try my hand at some modelers now. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map all the use cases and actors in StackOverflow you can take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and search for some known Q&A in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

And yes, if you want to make an exhaustive list, then you should include every actor - including Admin and Mediator. However, I'm not sure that you can figure out the admin's use cases (or other managing roles in this platform) since you are a user and it isn't reflected to you.

**If** there are use-cases that are unique to a specific actor, then you should add that actor to the diagram - and use inheritance! (When actor b has all the cases of a plus more, then b is inherits a) - this one is called "Generalization of an Actor" (you can google search some examples).

As for your other questions:

Please note that **Use Case Diagram** is an addition to the **Use Case Modeling**, more like an appendix. When you are modeling - you explain lots of details about the use case (some of them you've mentioned), such as: Primary actor, Scope, User Story, Postconditions, Preconditions, Triggers, Flow, and many more... There are a lot of templates actually. You can review them [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#Templates).

You do not describe **visually* any preconditions or post-conditions, however, you have some tools that can describe which cases are **included** in a specific case (in order to use feature Y - you should go over feature X). Or, which cases **extends** other cases (while you are using feature X, you can (but not have to) use feature Y).

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have come to know that I have been taught very basics of this concept. Trying to know more. :-)

Comment: Hey, if I am making an app to be submitted to a hackathon, similar to this one, should I include the admin side too?

Comment: @Nisha It depends on the orginaizers' submission requirements, ask them :)

Comment: Okay, Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use a modeler rather than to draw your diagram by hand.

> I want to improve this diagram to include an exhaustive list of all the features of Stack Overflow

The exhaustive list of the features of S.O. is certainly very be long, and you will have problem too see it because surely some parts are hidden to 'standard' users. What is your goal, to model S.O. or to use it as an exercise ? On the second case it is not necessary to manage *all*

> should there be another actor for Admin who manages user accounts, or not?

Sure they are admins or 'super' users.

> if we are asked for Use Cases, should we describe the inner functionalities, preconditions and postconditions of each use case separately?

A *use case* is not only an ellipse in a diagram, and a model is not ajust a list of diagrams. Yes each UC must have its description and the possible pre/post conditions etc

> What if other than these two actors, I decide to add a Mediator actor too ...

I don't know if there are mediators, but I am quite surprised by the 'mentor' whose role is to answer. If you have him you make a separation between the roles consisting to ask and to answer, so the other role cannot be the very general *user* but probably must be more specific

You will have lot of remarks about the UC *login* for sure ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am drawing this just as an exercise. And yes, I am still confused about all the talks about UC login, and I can't actually seem to decide where to fit it. I personally feel it an important function, but many stand against it. :) *Confused*